# How to quantify adulteration of urea and hydrogen per oxide in cow milk?

Tags: chemical-engineering, chemistry, spectrometry

I am very much new in this field and trying to get some information on adulteration of cow milk. I have searched and saw that mostly **urea** and **hydrogen per oxide** are mixed with cow milk.

I found that to quantify adulterants in milk, Fourier-transform infrared spectroscopy (**FTIR**) can be used. Normal cow milk contains **(20-70)mg/100ml** urea. So, urea content above **70mg/100ml** in milk is considered as added urea.

I want to know the exact proportion/amount of urea and hydrogen per oxide are mixed in the cow milk as adulterants. I need to carry out the experiment by adding urea/hydrogen per oxide in pure cow milk to get the desired spectrum in **FTIR**.

Is it in between 71-100mg or more or in which range actually?

Can anyone point me out any reference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hydrogen peroxide perhaps? Better on Biology or Chemistry stack...

Comment: Yes. I have added chemistry tag.

Comment: The Biology or chemistry Stacks may be a better fit for this question.

Comment: FTIR analysis falls squarely in the domain of chemistry SE.  This questions should definitely be moved over there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more on-topic at Chemistry.SE and has already been re-asked there: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99798/how-to-quantify-adulteration-of-urea-and-hydrogen-peroxide-in-cow-milk